# How to define all dependencies in one project?

Tags: architecture, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject.web.mvc

I have 6 projects.

1. **Asp.NET MVC 5 project**, which depense from **Service project** (e.g., Asp.NET project needed **IAccountService**, which is implemented in Service project).
2. **DependencyInjection project**, which have to manage dependencies in whole solution. This project have referense to Ninject, Ninject.Web.Common and Ninject.Web.Mvc. Now, this project do nothing.
3. **Domain project**, which contains POCO classes (e.g., class Account) and Contracts (e.g., **IAccountService**).
4. **Infrastructure project**, which contains Entity Framework, Repositories and **UnitOfWork**.
5. **Service project**, which implements **Domain Contracts** (e.g., Service project have class AccountService, which implement IAccountService). This project depends from **Infrastructure.UnitOfWork**.
6. **Test project.** It will test Service project.

Other words, there are the following diagram of dependencies:

1. Asp.NET MVC 5 -> Domain.Contracts
2. Domain have not any dependencies.
3. Infrastructure.UnitOfWork -> UnitOfWork.ApplicationDbContext
4. Service -> Infrastructure.UnitOfWork
5. Test project -> Domain.Contracts

I want to put all dependencies in DependencyInjection project. Abstractly, I want to put this code:

```
Bind<UnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
Bind<IAccountService>().To<AccountService>();
......
```

anywhere in DependencyInjection project. Then I want to write:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IAccountService accountService;

    public HomeController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        accountService.DepositMoney(10);

        return View();
    }
}
```

and have work application.

How I do this? I tried create classes, which inherit from NinjectModule (e.g., I have the following class:

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<UnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
        Bind<IAccountService>().To<AccountService>();
    }
}
```

Then, In Global.asax.cs (ASP.NET MVC 5 project) I write the following code:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new INinjectModule[]
        {
            new InfrastructureModule(),
            new ServiceModule()
        };

        var kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Then, I add the following code in Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="NinjectHttpModule" type="Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpModule"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

As a result, I have an exeption:

Error activating IntPtr
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:

3) Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor of type Func{IKernel}

2) Injection of dependency Func{IKernel} into parameter lazyKernel of constructor of type HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule

1) Request for IHttpModule

**I get confused. I'll be glad to any advice.**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612/126014

Comment: Related: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same

Comment: @Mark Seemann, thank you for links. I get valuable information.